# Use SQLBatch with fluent API?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jdbi

The docs describe using the SQLBatch annotation in the SQL Object API to do batching:

http://jdbi.org/jdbi2/sql_object_api_batching/

```
@SqlBatch("insert into something (id, name) values (:id, :first || ' ' || :last)")
  void insertFamily(@Bind("id") List<Integer> ids,
                    @Bind("first") Iterator<String> firstNames,
                    @Bind("last") String lastName);
```

Is it possible to perform batch SQL inserts using the fluent API as well?

```
String name = h.createQuery("select name from something where id = :id")
                    .bind("id", 1)
                    .map(StringColumnMapper.INSTANCE)
                    .first();
```

I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about JDBI v2, but in v3 it is done as in [docs](http://jdbi.org/#_prepared_batches):

```java
PreparedBatch batch = handle.prepareBatch("INSERT INTO user(id, name) VALUES(:id, :name)");
for (int i = 100; i < 5000; i++) {
    batch.bind("id", i).bind("name", "User:" + i).add();
}
int[] counts = batch.execute();
```

I am not really familiar with v2 codebase, but SqlObject plugin normally just uses usual fluent API under the hood, so it is highly likely that there is some sort of `PreparedBatch` too.